# Python contour analysis: How to handle letters like i or ö

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, ocr

Iam trying to extract letters and digits from a picture using the contours, but as you can see in the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBAk7.jpg), Iam having problem to recognize letters like i with separated dot.

How  could I solve such a issue?

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

contours = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = imutils.grab_contours(contours)

extracted_digits_letters = []

for contour in contours:
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)

    if cv2.contourArea(contour) > 50:
        digit_letter = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]

        resized_digit_letter = cv2.resize(digit_letter, (28, 28))

        extracted_digits_letters.append(resized_digit_letter)
```